We can't we simplify BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}" to BindingContext="{RelativeSource Self}"?
It is a trivial example to illustrate the problem.  I want to make the background color depend on the input.
<Entry
    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
// or
<Entry
    BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding Text}" />

Both work with the following output.

However if I simplify it as follows, it no longer works.
<Entry
    BindingContext="{RelativeSource Self}"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding Text}" />

As a comparison we can simplify
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource people}}"

to
ItemsSource="{StaticResource people}"

Question
What is the culprit?

Also, avoiding using source means you can make use of x:DataType and compiled binding optimizations.

The RelativeSource markup extension provides a RelativeBindingSource instance, which is not the actual object that you can fetch info from (however, it can be used as a source for the Binding extension).
In your first two examples the binding context for Entry is bound to actual object returned by {Binding}.
Compare that to ItemsSource, which needs a source and not actual object.

I still don't understand. Another comparison: Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource fullname}}" can be simplified to Text="{StaticResource fullname}".

If you look at the RelativeSourceExtension source code here, you'll see that it returns a RelativeBindingSource instance, which is not the actual object.

And if you look at the StaticResourceExtension code here, you'll see that it returns actual resource
